# Compute camera angles and locations given matching points with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I have stereo images (non co-planar cameras), which have matching points on a plane (wall) labeled.

I need to compute the camera locations in world space, and the angles they are focused at.

I can work out the math if I need to (with effort), I wonder if there is a shortcut to doing these computations in OpenCV that I might not be familiar with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are both looking at a plane, all you have to do is estimate homographies (with findHomography) independently between the plane and each camera, then decompose them (decomposeHomographyMat) to get rotation and translation up to scale. To resolve scale you need to know the distance between at least two of the points on the plane.